# AngularJS ng-repeat hide repeat item if it is not an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

Here is my JSON data i am using in my repeat :

```
{
"2": {
    "id": 3,
    "0": {
        "avatar": "http:\\/\\/localhost\\/pottero\\/wp-content\\/plugins\\/dokan-live-chat\\/assets\\/images\\/avatar.png",
        "message": "Hello",
        "id": "2",
        "class": ""
    },
    "1": {
        "avatar": "http:\\/\\/localhost\\/pottero\\/wp-content\\/plugins\\/dokan-live-chat\\/assets\\/images\\/avatar.png",
        "message": "Hello Again",
        "id": "2",
        "class": ""
    }
  }
}
```

my html ng-repeat :

```
<div ng-repeat="message in $ctrl.messages" class="chat-messages" data-user_id="{{message.id}}" id="chat-messages-{{message.id}}">
  <div ng-repeat="msg in message" class="message {{msg.class}}">
    <img ng-src="{{msg.avatar}}" />
      <div class="bubble">
        '<div ng-bind-html="msg.message | trusted_html"></div>
        <div class="corner"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

what i want to do is when msg is not an object like "id" : 3 which is not an object so i don't want it in the repeat like ng-if msg is not object then don't include it in the repeating loop? i used ng-if="typeof(msg) !== 'object'" but it does hides all items. Please point me out how can i hide repeat item if its not an object

Answer (score 0):

Convert each object to an array:

```
this.messages = Object.assign([], this.messages);
this.messages.forEach(msg => {
    msg = Object.assign([],msg));
});
```

When the `ng-repeat` directive iterates arrays, it only uses the properties that parse as integers.

For more information, see

- [MDN JavaScript Reference - Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)
- [MDN JavaScript Reference - array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score -1):

use `ng-container`. You cannot use `ng-repeat` and `ng-if` on same element. Also, `typeof` is not a function it is an operator. Use `ng-container` if you do not to stamp extra `html` else you can additional `div` and add your `ng-if` condition on that element.

```
<div ng-repeat="message in $ctrl.messages" class="chat-messages" data-user_id="{{message.id}}" id="chat-messages-{{message.id}}">
  <div ng-repeat="msg in message" class="message {{msg.class}}">
    <ng-container ng-if="typeof msg !== 'object'"> --> Or you can add here `div` or other html element
      <img ng-src="{{msg.avatar}}" />
        <div class="bubble">
          '<div ng-bind-html="msg.message | trusted_html"></div>
          <div class="corner"></div>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i am using it like this as a directive but its giving me `'<ng-container ng-if="typeof msg !== \'object\'">' +` syntaxt error?

Comment: Remove the backslash `<ng-container ng-if="typeof msg !== 'object' ">`